# linking shared library against static is not portable

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I'm trying to build and compile **ntop**.. I'm experiencing a problem here..

`sudo ./configure` is working fine..

when i go for `sudo make`, i get the below error..

```
*** Warning: Linking the shared library libntop.la against the
*** static library ./nDPI/src/lib/.libs/libndpi.a is not portable!

gcc: error: ./nDPI/src/lib/.libs/libndpi.a: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [libntop.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/ntop-5.0.1'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/ntop-5.0.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have googled many forum's regarding this.. But i did not get any answers.. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.. Thanks..

Comment: There seems to be a ntop package, at least for 12.04 LTS. Sometimes it is easiest to download this package (apt-get source ntop) and take a look at the debian/rules file to see how it is compiled.

Answer (score -2):

In Debian and Ubuntu, install MySQL solved this error!

```
aptitude install mysql-server
```

Comment: This is does not seem to answer the question.